# Updating solr configurations reloads tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, rsync

I am hosting solr in tomcat. I have several cores say under SOLR_DIR.

When I update configs on the server by doing an rsync on local machine on SOLR_DIR (no tomcat config files are touched), I observed that tomcat sometimes automatically reloads the solr webapp.

Why is this happening? Reloading solr webapp causes the server to be unresponsive for some time. I don't want it to happen. I would rather reload the cores to reflect the changes without restarting/reloading the whole tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak to unexpected Tomcat webapp reloads, but I hope this solution helps address the problem. When you change the `solrconfig.xml` file, you need to then reload at least the core in order to see the changes. Reloading the core alone will cause some amount of time where the core is unresponsive, and obviously reloading Tomcat will cause downtime for all of your cores. While I do this all the time in test-mode indexes, I generally find this unacceptable in a production environment.

My production solution has been replication. I build my index on one server, and replicate the core to a second. All index modifications occur in the build index, and all production queries point to the query index. When I've made a change to the build index, the query index pulls the change and keeps the old data and/or configuration running until the new version is ready and then swaps the change in *without detectable downtime*. This is a good framework for load balancing as well, since you can have multiple replicated query servers.

Make sure any conf files you want to be able to change against the live index are configured to replicate in the replication configuration. This is a bit tricky for the solr config because the replication configuration is in the `solrconfig.xml`, and if you set up the build core as master and the query core as slave, as soon as it replicates the query core will pull the build core's config. Then it will think it's the master and stop replicating any future changes.

I use **[this solution](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#enable.2Fdisable_master.2Fslave_in_a_node)**, which uses variables to set up the replication in the solr config, then provides values for those variables in a non-replicated `solrcore.properties` file in your core's `conf` folder.

From solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
<lst name="master">
    <str name="enable">${enable.master:false}</str>
    <str name="replicateAfter">startup,optimize</str>
    <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,solrconfig.xml,protwords.txt,synonyms.txt</str>
</lst>
<lst name="slave">
    <str name="enable">${enable.slave:false}</str>
    <str name="masterUrl">${master.url}</str>
    <str name="pollInterval">01:00:00</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

solrcore.properties:

```
enable.master=true
enable.slave=false
master.url=http://myserver.hostname/solr/coreName/replication
```

Note that any variables that you insert into your `solrconfig.xml` but fail to provide values for will cause the core to fail to load.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Firstly, reloading core is implemented in solr in an interesting way. They make a new copy of the core and then replace the existing one, which does not cause any downtime (at least something which is detectable). So, core reload is always preferable than reloading of tomcat.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion on replication, we also do the same (index replication), except the replication of configs. We instead copy the configs to replicas ourselves. Whatever the case is (replication of configs or manual copy), the core needs to be reloaded to reflect the changes.
My point in this question and the trouble was that whenever we change the configs (through rsync) in the server (be it core or replica), tomcat quite a few times roloads itself. I was trying to find what changes is causing tomcat to trigger auto-reload.

Comment: @krips89 My cores definitely stop responding for a while when I reload them, but maybe there's something different about my systems. Good luck with your work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what files you change.

Check your tomcat configuration and see if reloadable attribute is set to true

```
<Context reloadable="true" />
```

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development, but it requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for this attribute is false. You can use the Manager web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.

Comment: Yes I do have `reloadable="true"`. But the thing is I am not making any changes in the the solr classes/libraries. I am just updating the config directories of all the cores with an rsync.